# Bookshelf.js realtions, How can I fetch data from fourth table/model?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Here is the problem:-

table realtions
    `Cusomer -> hasMany Threads -> hasMany messages -> hasOne User (Who sent the message)`

I am able to get customer information with thread and thread's messages but not able to get the user information who has sent that message in this thread.
How I can get this information in same relation or way to get this?

```
// Controller
ChatCustomer
.where({
    'anonymous_id': anonymous_id,
    'company_id' : chatApplicationDetails.company_id
})
.fetch({withRelated: ['thread', 'thread.messages']});
```

What is required to get `thread.messages.customer` information?

```
// Customer model
var ChatCustomer = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'customers',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    hasTimestamps: ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
    company: function() {

        return this.belongsTo('Company');
    },
    thread: function(){

        return this.hasOne('ChatThread', 'customer_id');
    }
});

// Thred model
const ChatThread = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'threads',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    hasTimestamps: ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
    company: function () {

        return this.belongsTo('Company');
    },
    customer: function () {

        return this.belongsTo('ChatCustomer');
    },
    messages: function () {

        return this.hasMany('ChatMessage', 'thread_id');
    }
});

// Messages model
const ChatMessage = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'messages',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    hasTimestamps: ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
    thread: function () {

        return this.belongsTo('ChatThread');
    },
    user: function () {

        return this.hasOne('User', 'entity_id');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this even possible or not?

Comment: Have you even tried setting `withRelated: ['thread.messages.customer']`?

Comment: of course I did.

Comment: And what happened? You don't mention the results you got in that case, or even that you tried that.